# Can you get any information from your own mulligan?

Tags: hearthstone

When you mulligan cards in Hearthstone, they visibly fly back into your deck.  I feel like I've seen them sometimes aim for the upper portions, and sometimes they're near the bottom.  This leads me to wonder two things:

1. Am I actually seeing the cards reenter the deck at random locations?  Or is it my imagination?
2. If so, does that correspond in any way to when you'll actually draw that card?

Comment: Hahaha, the similarity to my own question makes me chuckle.  Anyway, I highly doubt the answer to #2 is yes. I'll keep an eye out for multiple animations though!

Comment: I sincerely believe all of this is your imagination. The animation runs client-side whereas what card you draw is decided server-side so there would have to be information about where each card is in your deck (if the server even keeps a shuffled version of the deck (which I doubt)) sent from the server to your client when you mulligan. It seems utterly foolish for such a message to be programmed in and I do not believe the Hearthstone devs are utterly foolish.

Comment: @ken.ganong ...unless they are total trolls.

Comment: @BlackVegetable - The similarity is deliberate.  I'd been wondering for a while, but your question prompted me to actually ask mine.  Thanks for the nudge!

Comment: @ken.ganong - I agree that it's unlikely and would be a strange choice, but neither of those are absolutes.  I strongly expect the answer to this to be "No", though.

Comment: @ken.ganong - Per the link in the answer, the server *does* keep a shuffled version, it just shuffles it again post-mulligan.

Comment: @Bobson That Twitter feed does appear to make this claim and from the lead developer, no less. There is now evidence that Hearthstone is making a really poor choice as to how to represent a shuffled deck in a digital card game--sad!

Comment: @ken.ganong - I'm not sure I agree.  Shuffling once and storing an indexed list of cards seems way more efficient than trying to determine which cards have been drawn and which haven't every time you need to draw a new one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After the mulligan, the deck is shuffled again for the match. So, no there is no way to guess when you actually draw a card.

Taken from the [Hearthstone Wiki](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Mulligan) with a link to [Ben Brode (Twitter)](https://twitter.com/bdbrode/status/557442435798671360), Senior Game Designer on Hearthstone at Blizzard Entertainment.

> They are however returned to the deck after the mulligan is complete, to be drawn during the following match. The remaining deck is shuffled or randomised once the mulligan is complete

Comment: Perfect!  A developer comment is, by far, the best source we can have.  Thanks for finding that!